# EF Core LINQ query experts needed

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

EF Core and .NET 5.x

My problem is defining with linq / query how to get this result. A total of 7 tables has to be joined. For simplicity the 7 tables is simplified. the sql at the bottom is the result i want to get where the so far line code is.

```
public class SP 
{
    int     spKey { get; set; }
    string  spValue { get; set; }
}

public class SV 
{
    int     svKey { get; set; }
    string  svValue { get; set; }
}

public class IR 
{
    int     irKey { get; set; }
    string  irValue { get; set; }
}

public class UR 
{
    int     urKey { get; set; }
    string  urValue { get; set; }
}

public class BE 
{
    int     beKey { get; set; }
    string  beValue { get; set; }
    int     irKey { get; set; }
    int     urKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("irKey")]
    public  IR { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("urKey")]
    public  UR { get; set; }
}

public class SO 
{
    int     soKey { get; set; }
    int     beKey { get; set; }
    int     spKey { get; set; }
    int     svKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("beKey")]
    public  BE { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("spKey")]
    public  SP { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("svKey")]
    public  SV { get; set; }
}

public class SD 
{
    int     soKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("soKey")]
    public  SO { get; set; } 
}
```

The following SQL is the result I would like to have:

```
select *
from SD t_sd
left outer join SO t_so on t_so.soKey = t_sd.soKey
left outer join BE t_be on t_be.beKey = t_so.beKey
left outer join IR t_ir on t_ir.irKey = t_be.irKey
left outer join UR t_ur on t_ur.urKey = t_be.urKey
left outer join SP t_sp on t_sp.spKey = t_so.spKey
left outer join SV t_sv on t_sv.svKey = t_so.svKey
where t_so.beKey = 4711 and t_sp.spValue = 'test'
```

Using EF Core and ASP.NET Core 5.

I am stuck at using `.Include` / `.ThenInclude` in LINQ

```
public SalgDetail GetBestilling(long bestilNr)
{
    using (var _db = new DbContext(conString))
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _db.SD
                .Include(sd => sd.SO)
                    .ThenInclude(so => so.BE)
                        .ThenInclude(b => b.IR)
                .Include(sd => sd.SO)
                    .ThenInclude(so => so.BE)
                        .ThenInclude(b => b.UR)
                .Include(sd => sd.SO)
                    .ThenInclude(so => so.SP)
                .Include(sd => sd.SO)
                    .ThenInclude(so => so.SV);

// where do I put my 'where' clauses        
            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the final result?

Comment: You should just put the `Where` after the `Include`s and `ThenInclude`s referencing the fields via `sd`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your Includes, `where` is simple:

```cs
var query = _db.SD
    .Include(sd => sd.SO.BE.IR)
    .Include(sd => sd.SO.BE.UR)
    .Include(sd => sd.SO.SP)
    .Include(sd => sd.SO.SV)
    .Where(sd => sd.SO.beKey == 4711 && sd.SO.SP.spValue == "test");

var result = query.ToList();
```